# Use custom build command texniccenter

Tags: texniccenter, customize, engine

I do have a quite uncommon setting it appears. Running texniccenter on a Windows machine but not being able to install any LaTeX engine, I chose to use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to run texlive. The following works from a cmd.exe

``` powershell -Command "wsl cd ``wslpath -u C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents\Tex\`` `&`& lualatex test.tex" ```

Having this working just as expected, I thought I could create a new profile where the LaTeX compiler is

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

and

``` powershell -Command "wsl cd ``wslpath -u %DM`` `&`& lualatex %nm" ```

is the argument passed, should do the trick. Unfortunately it doesn't ):
Any thoughts on this?

Cheers.
Christian

Comment: Forgot to mention I also tried the compiler to be ```C:\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe``` and the argument ```"wsl cd ``wslpath -u %DM`` `&`& lualatex %nm"```